# How image upload works with Dropzone.js?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, cropperjs

I guess if I have a `form` with `action` and `class="dropzone`, then after drop an image in the drop zone, fill upload to the specified image, right?

Why someone adds `success` event in `init` to Dropzone instead of add as `action`?

```js
init: function() {
 landingDropzone = this
 this.on("processing", function(file) {
  this.options.url = file.uploadURL
 });
 this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/api/campaign/#(campaign.id)/client_image",
```

What if I do further manipulation of the image, i.e. I crop it with Cropper.js? Shall I use then `success` event?

Comment: Hello, I have upvoted your question because somebody downvoted it for no apparent reason.